# Chain of responsiblity lambda function

Tags: java, lambda

```
@Component
public class UserChain {
 
        @Autowired
        private List<UserChain> userchains;
 
        public User enrichUser(User user) {
                for (UserChain userChain: userchains) {
                        userChain.enrich(user);
                }
                return user;
        }
}
```

How can I convert the `enrichUser` method to a lambda function?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "convert to a lambda function"? Please provide an example, at least in pseudocode, of what you have in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to pass the `UserChain` and the `User` to the lambda you can do it with a `BiFunction` functional interface.

- the first two types are the chain and the user (arguments to apply)
- the third is the return type

```
BiFunction<List<UserChain>, User, User> enrich =
        (uchain, user) -> {
            for (UserChain uch : uchain) {
                uch.enrich(user);
            }
            return user;
        };
User user = ... some user
user = enrich.apply(userchains, user);
```

Or a `Function<User,User>` if you want to reference the `List<UserChain>` field directly.

**Possible alternative approach**

If the supplied object is mutable and is simply updated and returned, then you can  use a `BiConsumer`.

```
BiConsumer<List<UserChain>, User> enrich =
        (uchain, u) -> uchain.forEach(uc->uc.enrich(u));
        
enrich.accept(userchains, user); // now user has the enrichments.
```

You could also use a `Consumer` if you want to reference (not pass as an argument) the `List<UserChain>`.

```
Consumer<User> enrich = u-> userchains.forEach(uc->uc.enrich(u));
enrich.accept(user);
```

Answer (score 1):

The function you have takes `User` as input and returns `User` as output.
Hence we will need an object of type `Function<User, User>` to store the function code.

```
public class UserChain {

    @Autowired
    private List<UserChain> userchains;
    public Function<User, User> enrichUser = user -> { 
        userchains.forEach(userChain -> userChain.enrich(user));
        return user;
    };
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: The question is asking to convert a function to lambda. What other context is required? Its a fairly simple question.

Comment: Please add all such explanation to your answer by editing it. Keep in mind that others should be able to learn from your answer

Comment: Would love to, but not able to understand what other explanation is required.

Comment: Feel free to edit the answer and add anything you feel is missing.

Comment: @AnmolSinghJaggi Explaining how you went from his method to yours (such as why the return type matters) would be the "other explanation". Your answer currently passes him the code without explanation, making this post useless for others reading this wanting to learn. Doesn't help the OP either, as they won't know how to convert methods to lambdas properly on their own, since you don't explain how you formulated your solution.

Comment: Edited to add more details.

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
userchains.forEach(uc -> uc.enrich(user));
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to quite match what he's looking for, but if it is, you can simplify it as `forEach(UserChain::enrich)`.

Comment: He explicitly requested lambda, not method reference. That is why I posted the answer like that. @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-

Comment: I don't believe either of those satisfy the requirement.  The OP wants to **convert**  the `enrichUser` method to a `lambda`.  Those require the method to still exist.

Comment: @WJS Ok. I thought that he means the contents/current implementation. If this is not the case, he will have to declare it as a Function<User, User>, as in the response from Anmol